# Change the format of hard drive in Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Windows not recognize files inside Linux partitions?](https://superuser.com/questions/403805/why-does-windows-not-recognize-files-inside-linux-partitions)

I had three drives in my Windows in NTFS format. I going to install Ubuntu 12.4 inside Windows.

In one of the steps of installation I should chose drive for install Ubuntu. I separate 80 GB from one of the drives for " / " and 8 GB for the swap area from another drive.

I stop installation after this step. But when I was in Windows, I couldn't see those drives!
I think that Windows can't see this drive because I change the format of the drives.

How do I change the format of those drives? In it, I have very important documentation and files.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understood correctly: You lost access to files, that were previously accessible from within Windows? Did you resize the partition, containing these files? Or did you delete or reformat it? The installer should have warned you about that data loss in  the latter case.

Comment: @GurkenPapst, yes I resize the partition.I separate 80 GB from one partition and 8 GB from anther partition for sowap.previously my partition's format was NTFS and installer warned that can't install ubuntu in this type (NTFS) and I change the type to ext2.
So , my friend I don't need Ubuntu and I want to change type of drives permanently for windows.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you did. I assume, that your important files were on the NTFS partition? Did you change a) (reduce) the size of your NTFS partition to gain free space, where you created new **additional** partitions or b) **change** the type of the NTFS partition to ext2 by formatting it. For the latter option, data loss has to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that when you installed ubuntu, you formatted the drives to use the [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) or [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) filesystem that Windows does not natively support. If so you have two options, either reformat the drives to NTFS or a filesystem that both [Windows and Ubuntu support](http://www.howtogeek.com/73178/what-file-system-should-i-use-for-my-usb-drive/) (requires reinstallation of Ubuntu), or [install a tool](http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows) on Windows that allows you to read/write to the ext2/3 filesystem.

Comment: this tool not work in windows7.any other? my friend I don't need Ubuntu and I want to change type of drives permanently for windows.